# How to control the depth of php infinite pole classification

Tags: php, algorithm

Here is my array:

```
 $list = array(
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Phones', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        array('id' => 256, 'name' => 'Accessories', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        array('id' => 308, 'name' => 'Appliances', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        array('id' => 1057, 'name' => 'Smart', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        array('id' => 1065, 'name' => 'Smart Phones', 'parent_id' => 3,),
        array('id' => 1066, 'name' => 'Feature Phones', 'parent_id' => 3,),
        array('id' => 1069, 'name' => 'Samsung', 'parent_id' => 1065,),
        array('id' => 1070, 'name' => 'Apple', 'parent_id' => 1065,),
        array('id' => 1072, 'name' => 'Apple', 'parent_id' => 1066,),
        array('id' => 1075, 'name' => 'Tablets', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        array('id' => 1076, 'name' => 'Samsung', 'parent_id' => 1066,),
        array('id' => 1077, 'name' => 'All Brands', 'parent_id' => 1075,),
        array('id' => 1078, 'name' => 'Samsung', 'parent_id' => 1077,),
        array('id' => 1079, 'name' => 'Protector', 'parent_id' => 256,),
        array('id' => 1080, 'name' => 'Power', 'parent_id' => 256,),
        array('id' => 1081, 'name' => 'Cable', 'parent_id' => 256,),
        array('id' => 1082, 'name' => 'Memory', 'parent_id' => 256,),
    );
```

This is the code I categorized：

```
function  quote_make_tree($list,$deep=1, $root = 0)
{
    $tree = $packData = [];
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $packData[$row['id']] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($packData as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['parent_id'] == $root) {
            $tree[] = &$packData[$key];
        } else {
            $packData[$val['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$packData[$key];

        }

    }
    return $tree;
}
```

I want to add a deep parameter `$deep` to `quote_make_tree` to control the depth of classification.

The result I want:
If $deep = 1 Get only data with parent_id = 0:

```
 $one = array(
        0 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Phones', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        1 => array('id' => 256, 'name' => 'Accessories', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        2 => array('id' => 308, 'name' => 'Appliances', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        3 => array('id' => 1057, 'name' => 'Smart', 'parent_id' => 0,),
        4 => array('id' => 1075, 'name' => 'Tablets', 'parent_id' => 0,),
    );
```

If $deep = 2，Get level 2 classification below level 1 classification,if $deep=3,Get all 1,2,3 classifications

I have tried get all the data first, then delete the data according to `$deep`.here is [demo](https://3v4l.org/cYU7h),thanks folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be easier to solve using a recursive method.  This allows you to check the depth and if you want more details then it will call itself to add in more layers.  Each time calling itself you just take one off the depth...

```
function  quote_make_tree($list, $deep=1, $root = 0) {
    $output = [];
    foreach ( $list as $listItem )  {
        if ( $listItem['parent_id'] == $root ) {
            if ( $deep > 1 )    {
                $listItem['children'] = quote_make_tree($list, $deep-1, $listItem['id']);
            }
            $output[] = $listItem;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really simpler to use recursion

Comment: If you don't want to limit depth, your method is shorter as it makes less passes of the data, this will scan all of the data for each call.

Comment: The classification level of my database is at most 3